# discord v12 Hello, why does user.presence.status return offline even if the user is online?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

why does user.presence.status return offline even if the user is online?

```
const user = mess.mentions.users.first()  || mess.author;
const status = user.presence.status
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you did not enable the `PRESENCE` intent in the settings of your application. Go to https://discord.dev, then click on your application, go to the "BOT" page and enable both intents. Restart your bot, and the user presence should be the right one!